# Как вывести одну строку из файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим у меня есть файл:

```
15
622
644
876
213
456
```

.

```
r = random.randint(0, count)
#count - это переменная, в которой содержится общее кол-во строк)
```

Мне нужно вывести строку, которую определит рандом. Как это сделать?

Comment: Пройти в цикле до нужной строки и вывести ее.

Answer (score 5):

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией `random.choice`, передав ей в качестве аргумента список строк из файла.

***Пример:***

```py
import random


def main():
    with open('file.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    random_line = random.choice(lines)
    print(random_line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Просто как вариант, плюс в том что файл не всегда читается полностью, есть какой-то бесполезный chance-вероятность, но random.choice наверное предпочтительней, если файл не слишком велик.

А если заранее известно кол-во строк файла, то можно однократно вычислить random.randint(0, lines_len) и читать файл только до этой строки, а не полностью.

```
import random


def main(chance=20):
    with open('file.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            if random.randint(1, 101) <= chance:
                break
    return line


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main())
```